# how to submit the values in the form in javascript when there are 2 submit values?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one form where there are 2 inputs those are submit type of inputs like this.

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="payee" value="">
    <input type="text" name="amount" value="">
    <input type="text" name="date" value="">
    <input type="submit" name="deposit" value="Distribute">
    <input type="submit" name="distribute" value="Deposit">
</form>
```

In jQuery like this:

```
$("form submit").click(function() {
    // i wrote code.
}
```

If I click on the `deposit` button some action should occur. If I click on the `distribute` button some other action should occur.

Answer (score 5):

First of all you need to change your `submit` inputs to buttons (or at least one of them) as 2 submit buttons in 1 form is invalid. Then give each button its' own `Id`.

```
<input type="button" name="deposit" value="Distribute" id="distribute">
<input type="button" name="distribute" value="Deposit" id="deposit">
```

Then, in jQuery you can then use the `Id` of each button to run specific code when it is clicked, like this:

```
$("#distribute").click(function() {
    // code to run when distribute is clicked
}
$("#deposit").click(function() {
    // code to run when deposit is clicked
}
```

Comment: Still I would leave one of the buttons as submit type so that hitting Enter withing the form would also cause form submission.

Answer (score 0):

insert another input type  :

```
<input type="hidden" name="hf" id="hf" value="">
```

and

```
$("form :submit").click(function() {
  if ($(this).attr('id')=='distribute') $("#hf").val('sent by distribute');
else $("#hf").val('sent by deposit');
}
```

and in the server you can see who send by reading the hiddenField value ( hf)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom attribute on your buttons in document.ready function and on click of the button you can identify which button has posted an request to form.

Example to add custom attribute

```
<input type="submit" id="deposit" value="Distribute">
<input type="submit" id="distribute" value="Deposit">


$(function () {
$("#deposit").attr('isDeposit','1');
$("#distribute").attr('isDeposit','0');

});
```

and on submit click

```
$("form submit").click(function()
{
var identifyButton = $(this).attr('isDeposit');
}
```

some thing like this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the jQuery submit() function, like this:

```
$('#deposit').submit(function(){
  //Code to run
});
```

It's better because you can cancel the client event, if some field is wrong.

http://api.jquery.com/submit/

You don't need a plugin to do it, however there's a lot of them:
http://www.designyourway.net/blog/resources/55-jquery-form-plugins-to-download-and-use/